# Inkscape: swatch color setup missing from swatches list

Tags: inkscape, swatches

I have created a swatch file for Inkscape:

```
GIMP Palette
Name: My-Ca

50  43  2b  beige foncé
57  4b  2e  beige moyen
a7  96  6b  beige clair
fb  e3  bd  beige pâle
2c  50  3a  vert terne
33  4c  27  vert vif
57  2f  4a  violet sombre
96  52  80  violet clair
e4  90  3e  orange
e5  bc  71  jaune
13  1a  12  noir
```

I have set it up into the system with the help of a soft link:

```
ln -s /home/lalebarde/Documents/Flyer/Ressources/inkscape-colors.gpl /usr/share/inkscape/palettes/My-Ca.gpl
```

But it does not show up into the Inkscape swatches list, though it is the second one I have created, and **it is alright for the first one**.

```
ls -l /usr/share/inkscape/palettes/My-Ca.gpl 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 91 Jul 22 08:11 /usr/share/inkscape/palettes/My-Ca.gpl -> /home/lalebarde/Documents/Flyer/Ressources/inkscape-colors.gpl
ls -l /home/lalebarde/Documents/Flyer/Ressources/inkscape-colors.gpl
-rw-r--r-- 1 alain alain 286 Jul 22 08:10 /home/lalebarde/Documents/Flyer/Ressources/inkscape-colors.gpl
```

Restarting Inkscape or rebooting does not help.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Just as a test: does it work if you place the file directly in the plalettes folder, e.g. not as a link?

Comment: If the file's syntax is correct, then try putting it into the correct folder, which is /home/username/.config/inkscape/palettes . My Gimp palette files have a # in front of the empty line after the 'Name' line, not sure if that's important.

Comment: @samcarter : no

Comment: If I replace your hex values with rgb between 0 and 255, the palette seems to work

Comment: You got it, values shall be in decimal, I have also tried with prefixing with 0x without success. Please turn it as answer

Comment: @lalebarde Great to hear that its working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hex values, the colours need to be defined in decimal values between 0 and 255. For example:

```
GIMP Palette
Name: My-Ca

80 67 43 beige foncé
```